# Violation of Primary Key constraint windowsForms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I would like to insert a record into my RDV Table.

This is the query creation of my table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RDV] (
[idRdv]       INT           NOT NULL,
[objet]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[objectif]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[DateRdv]     DATETIME      NULL,
[commentaire] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[archive]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[idClient]    INT           NULL,
[idUser]      INT           NULL,
[idResultat]  INT           NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_RDV] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([idRdv] ASC),
FOREIGN KEY ([idClient]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Client] ([idClient]),
FOREIGN KEY ([idUser]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([idUser]),
FOREIGN KEY ([idResultat]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Resultat] ([idResultat]);
```

and this is my code of insert

```
 public RDV()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox3.Visible = false;
        label7.Visible = false;

    }
  private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rdm = new Random();
        int num = rdm.Next(5, 2000);
        textBox3.Text = num.ToString();

        string cmdStr = "Insert into RDV (idRdv,idUser,idClient,objet,objectif,DateRdv,commentaire) select @idRdv,@idUser,@idClient,@objet,@objectif,@DateRdv,@commentaire from RDV, Client, [User] where RDV.idClient = Client.idClient and RDV.idUser = [User].idUser ";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=timar;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idRdv", textBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUser", (comboBox1.SelectedValue));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idClient", (comboBox2.SelectedValue));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objet", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objectif", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateRdv", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commentaire", textBox4.Text);

        con.Open();
        int LA = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Ligne ajoutée: {0}", LA);
```

And,the field **idRdv** , i want to add it but should be hidden and Random like in the code above.

When , I run my project , it shows me an error **Violation of PRIMARY KEY " PK_RDV ". Can not insert duplicate key in object ' dbo.RDV ".  Value of Duplicate Key:1505 (this the value of idRdv)**

Pleaaaaseee, help me. How should I correct it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have one primary key on that table. It means you cannot insert the same value twice. You are trying to do that. How should you correct it? Do not try to insert that same value again. It's as simple as that. The _real_ question is, how do you make sure this doesn't happen again? The answer to that is: think again about how you generate your idRdv. Inserting random numbers and hoping that it works is generally not a good strategy.

Comment: Please, Have you any other idea ?

Comment: Filling technical keys can be done by the database, you can do it yourself by using MAX(idRdv)+1, you could change it to a Guid, etc, etc, etc.. There are many options for this, each with their own advantages and disadvantages. You _could_ even use a random number and first check if it exists, then handle the error in any way your want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the ID with `Random`. As your table ID column is containing `Primary Key Constraint` it may get this error.

Either you check that the random number generated is not exist in the table before insert. Or use a method to get `Max(ID)+1` and set this as new ID

Comment: I check t, the random number generated doesn't exist in the table. I don't understand how it's duplicate !!

Comment: Better you avoid the `Random` number concept for ID column, get the MAX ID + 1 and insert with that value

Comment: I've tested with max(idRdv) +1 and it doesn't work . The same error shown

Comment: `string cmdStr = "Insert into RDV (idRdv,idUser,idClient,objet,objectif,DateRdv,commentaire) select max(@idRdv)+1,@idUser,@idClient,@objet,@objectif,@DateRdv,@commentaire from RDV, Client, [User] where RDV.idClient = Client.idClient and RDV.idUser = [User].idUser ";`

Comment: I have delete  now all  the records in my DB so **Can not insert the value NULL into column ' idRdv ' table '**

Comment: Not `max(@idRdv)+1` use the column name instead. That is `max(idRdv)+1`

Comment: Sorry for omitted the `ISNULL` part. Please use `ISNULL(MAX(idRdv), 0) + 1`. So you can do it with empty table